# Programmatic autolayout issues

Tags: ios7, autolayout

I'm attempting to implement a dynamic layout using autolayout constraints; for that purpose I have created 3 container views. The first one that is 49 height, flexible width. The second one that is 320 height and 320 width and the last one that is 69 height flexible width. So here's the code that is supposed to place each view below the other.

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(searchControlsView, workArtView, playBackControlsContainer);
    // Position time search controls

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[searchControlsView]|"
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[searchControlsView]"
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    // position workArt
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[workArtView]|"
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[searchControlsView]-0-[workArtView]"
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    // position bottom controls
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[playBackControlsContainer]|"
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[workArtView]-(>=0)-[playBackControlsContainer]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

What I want to achieve is the last view to be below the 2nd one If possible, if not the third view will be aligned at the bottom of entire screen and overlap the 2nd one. However, the third view (playBackControlsContainer) is not being shown in screen.

Previous to this I removed all the constraints from the view. I tried several things but I just starting with programmatic constraints and I am not able to realize where I am failing... besides that the debug log has lots of additional views and without and identifier for the addresses of each control it's really difficult to figure out why my layout might be ambiguous. Here's the debug log in case is useful.

```
*<UIWindow:0xc1a6510> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   *<UILayoutContainerView:0xc1b6b50>
|   |   *<UITransitionView:0xc1a3da0>
|   |   |   *<UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc3b82b0>
|   |   |   |   *<UIView:0xc1b9830>
|   |   |   |   |   *<UILayoutContainerView:0xc1ba6a0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   *<UINavigationTransitionView:0xc1bf490>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc1c5110>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0xb478820> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0xb4f9d70> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0xb4f3e40>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xc4e7030>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0xb4f5440>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xc14b0a0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButtonLabel:0xb4fb610> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0xb4f0e80>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xc1f00b0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButtonLabel:0xb4fac70> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0xb4f04f0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xc129480>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButtonLabel:0xb4fa2e0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0xb478790>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIImageView:0xb4f9b60>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<LVStopWatchLabel:0xb479200>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xb478920>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIView:0xb479940>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UIButton:0xb4f6ab0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xc4e6c00>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UILabel:0xb479db0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<UISlider:0xb4f5e90>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0xc4e05e0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0xc4e0760>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0xc4e0880>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0xc4e5c40>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xc4e67d0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xc4e5d40>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0xb478440> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   *<_UILayoutGuide:0xb4782a0> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UINavigationBar:0xc1c4a10>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UINavigationBarBackground:0xc1c7530>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIImageView:0xc1c7810>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UINavigationItemView:0xc4cf610>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UILabel:0xc4dcae0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UINavigationItemButtonView:0xc4dcf10>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UILabel:0xc4dcfe0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView:0xc3c3880>
|   |   |   |   |   <GADBannerView:0xc3de310>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <GADWebView:0xc3de440>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   <_UIWebViewScrollView:0xc3e01a0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   <UIWebBrowserView:0xd280600>
|   |   |   |   |   <ADBannerView:0xc19ad20>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <ADRemoteView:0xc19cca0>
|   |   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0xc19d590>
|   |   <UITabBar:0xb4a47e0>
|   |   |   <_UITabBarBackgroundView:0xc47db60>
|   |   |   |   <_UIBackdropView:0xc47d240>
|   |   |   |   |   <_UIBackdropEffectView:0xc47e490>
|   |   |   |   |   <UIView:0xc47e530>
|   |   |   <UITabBarButton:0xc19ed40>
|   |   |   |   <UITabBarSwappableImageView:0xc17ee00>
|   |   |   |   <UITabBarButtonLabel:0xc19f170>
|   |   |   <UITabBarButton:0xc1a4120>
|   |   |   |   <UITabBarSwappableImageView:0xc1a3570>
|   |   |   |   <UITabBarButtonLabel:0xc1a3e60>
|   |   |   <UITabBarButton:0xc1a62b0>
|   |   |   |   <UITabBarSwappableImageView:0xc1a6660>
|   |   |   |   <UITabBarButtonLabel:0xc1a6390>
|   |   |   <UITabBarButton:0xc1a8a30>
|   |   |   |   <UITabBarSwappableImageView:0xc1a9080>
|   |   |   |   <UITabBarButtonLabel:0xc1a8f60>
|   |   |   <UIImageView:0xc47ead0>
```

Any help to figure out what might be the reason for this I would be really thankful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're forgetting to set the heights of your views.

For example,

```
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[searchControlsView(49)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
```

Comment: Well, the height and width constraints are added using interface builder to each view. The should be there even if I remove the constraints from the superview.

Comment: Ok, then I need more information. I don't have a complete picture of the constraints in play. Since you are using the visual format language, I thought the layout was defined only by the code above.